# Prove that A¯⊆ B if (C-B) ∪ A = A, where Ω is the universal set and A, B, C are subsets of it.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Ok this question bothers me. I am stuck on it and I actually think the text book might have incorrectly worded the question.

Using direct proof:
 I assume A¯⊆ B. So this piece, along with the fact that A,B,C ⊆ U are the only pieces of information I have.

How can I make my way to show that (C-B) ∪ A = A if I have almost no information on C?
Am I supposed to assume that A ∪ B ∪ C = U or something? I don't know how I can make any kind of statement about C without knowing its true.

If you could give me a hint in the right direction, or solve the problem, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks,
John

Comment: If you think the problem is wrong, try to come up with a counterexample.

Comment: Could it be that you need to prove $\bar A \subseteq B \iff (C\setminus B) \cup A = A$ *for all* $C$?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Hmm maybe that is what they meant I will email the prof.

Comment: @Surb A−  is the compliment of A (just the syntax my textbook uses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the claim should be:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $\Omega$.  Then $\bar A \subseteq B$ if and only if $(C \setminus B) \cup A = A$ for all subsets $C \subseteq \Omega$.

Before diving in, let's remember:

- For sets $X,Y \subseteq \Omega$, $\bar X \subseteq Y \iff \bar Y \subseteq X$.
- For sets $X,Y$, $X \subseteq Y \iff X \cup Y = Y$.

**Proof.**

- ($\Rightarrow$): Suppose that $\bar A \subseteq B$, and let $C \subseteq \Omega$.  Then
  $$
      (C \setminus B) = C \cap \bar B \subseteq \bar B \subseteq A
  $$
  and this means that $(C \setminus B) \cup A = A$.
- ($\Leftarrow$): Suppose that $(C \setminus B) \cup A = A$ for all subsets $C \subseteq \Omega$.  Let $C = \bar B$.  Then
  $$
      (C \setminus B) = \bar B \setminus B = \bar B
  $$
  so $\bar B \cup A = A$. Therefore $\bar B \subseteq A$, which means $\bar A \subseteq B$.